# How to use development database for only one model in Rspec/Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd, cucumber

I have a dictionary application which has a lot of word definitions in the development database. When I'm writing my Cucumber/Rspec tests I usually populate the test db with a few words that I know I'm gonna be using in the test. However, it would be great if I could access the development db for only one model (Word) to check the word definition, and use the test db for everything else. How can that be set up?

Comment: you;d rather seed your test db

Answer (score -1):

It's an hard-if-not-impossible task to achieve, for one reason: you should not do that.

Tests must be independent from your development environment. If you run the tests via a continuous integration tool (as it is recommended), the test environment is every time build from 0, with no knowledge of previous states.

If you need some records to be present for your test to run, then seed your test with the necessary records. That's the way to do it.

Comment: I know about independent test environment. The Word model consists of 110349 records, so building that every time would be really time-consuming. I was just wondering whether this sort of setup was possible at all. If not, I will just seed the records used in tests.

Comment: Do you really need all those records to unit test your model? If that's the case, there is a decoupling issue in your test.

Comment: Technically I dont need but it would make things easier. For example, I have a chine text that has 100+ characters in it and I  select a few random characters from it to form a test for users. When I do that, I need to find those words in dictionary (Word model). I can populate the test db with only words for the texts Im using but it seems quite laborious.